# how can I get just a single div to refresh on submit as apposed to the entire page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working with a dynamically generated page written in PHP. The page contain contents listed, while clicking the edit link a new page will open as popup using fancybox . Once editing is complete and the user closes the FancyBox modal the changes need to be reflected on the parent page.

Right, so I was able to find a solution that refreshes the entire page on submit using

```
  parent.location.reload (true);
```

to refresh the entire parent page. But, that causes a browser prompt that is confusing to users and a bit of over kill as I really only need the information edited to refresh.

how can I get just a single div to refresh on submit as apposed to the entire page??????